# How to calculate $\iint_S~F \cdot n dS$ for the following.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to calculate $$\iint_S~F \cdot n dS$$ when $n$ is the unit normal vector to the surface, $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and the surface in question is $$x^2 - y^2 + z^2 = 0,~ y \in [0, 1] $$

So far here is what I have attempted, I have paramaterised the surface as

$$r(\alpha,\beta)=(\alpha \cos(\beta),\alpha, \alpha \sin (\beta)),~\alpha \in [0,1],~\beta \in [0,2\pi]$$

I have also found $$|r_\alpha \times r_\beta|=\sqrt{2}\alpha$$

but I'm unsure how to proceed to be honest. I need to find a normal vector for each point on the surface (I'm not sure how to do this) and then some how evaluate the integral. Any ideas please?

---

I have now solved the problem here is the solution for anyone interested:

The unit normal vector turns out to be $$\frac{r_\alpha \times r_\beta}{|r_\alpha \times r_\beta|}$$ then the integral we want to evaluate is $$\int^{2\pi}_0\int^1_0r\cdot |r_\alpha \times r_\beta| d\alpha d\beta=0 $$. So the flux of $F$ across $S$ is $0$.

Comment: There's a weird symbol after $x^2$ in my browser: . What is this supposed to be?

Comment: The minus symbol.

Comment: I have now solved my problem, is the etiquette to post the answer I found or what?

Comment: @AndrewClinton Yes! It's even encouraged since you found an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that for your parameterisation $ \vec{r}(\alpha, \beta)$, we have that $$ \iint \mathbf{F} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \text{ d}S = \iint \mathbf{F} \cdot \underbrace{ \ \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \alpha} \times \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \beta} \right)}{{ \left\| \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \alpha} \times \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \beta} \right\|}}}_{= \ \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ } \  \ \overbrace{ \ \left\| \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \alpha} \times \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \beta} \right\| \text{ d}\alpha \text{ d}\beta \ }^{= \ \text{ d}S}$$

Comment: Ah, I see that you already have it. Was having problems with the $\LaTeX$ so I couldn't get the answer up before you got it!